# Returning largest value in javascript object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for a simple solution to find the largest integer in an object I have the following object named `numberZeros`

```
Object {0: 3, 1: 3, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 5}
```

Here is how I am trying to see which one has the largest value but it returns undefined.

```
Array.max = function( numberZeros ){
    console.log(Math.max.apply( Math, numberZeros));
};
```

I am guessing it is because it does not work on objects. How would I get it to return `8: 5`?

Comment: You iterate manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `.apply` needs an array instead of an object.

And in your case, you <del>should</del> could use an array instead of an object. (Edit: sorry I didn't see it was sparse)

But you can use

```
var obj = {0: 3, 1: 3, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 5},
    max = -Infinity;
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        max = Math.max(max, obj[i]);
    }
}
```

But I think the following is better:

```
var arr = [3, 3,, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5],
    max = Math.max.apply(null, arr);
```

---

It seems you want to get [argmax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argmax) instead of [max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum). Then, use

```
var obj = {0: 3, 1: 3, 3: 2, 4: 3, 5: 4, 6: 2, 7: 3, 8: 5},
    max = -Infinity,
    argmax = void(0);
for(var i in obj) {
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i) && obj[i] >= max) {
        max = obj[i];
        argmax = i;
    }
}
```

or

```
var arr = [3, 3,, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 5],
    max = -Infinity,
    argmax = void(0);
for(var i=0, l=arr.length; i<l; ++i) {
    if(arr[i] >= max) {
        max = obj[i];
        argmax = i;
    }
}
```

Note: I have used `>=` in case all values in object/array are `-Infinity`, in order to have an `argmax`. If you are sure there will be at least one value greater than `-Infinity`, you can use `<` and gain some microseconds.

Comment: I have to keep it as an object because of the index in front of the largest number

Comment: @megawac Good point, but not before ES5, so I'm not sure if it would work on all browsers.

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Then, do you want to get `argmax` instead of `max`?

Comment: I need it to return the exactly `8: 5` it cant just be `5` so if that is what argmax would do then yes

Comment: if you look closely at the object you see that it goes `1: 3, 3: 2` 2 is not in there

Comment: @Yamaha32088 Oh, I didn't see it, fixed.